# Azure Devops install Python package from Azure Artifacts inside Docker

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to install a pip package from Azure Artifacts as part of a Docker image(with `Docker@2` task) but whatever I try does not work.

It looks like my `pip` inside Docker cannot authenticate against Azure Artifacts whatever I try. Closest I got is with

```
RUN pip install keyring artifacts-keyring
ENV ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE true
RUN pip install <> --index-url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<>/_packaging/<>/pypi/simple/
```

but in my Azure devops, i keep getting

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <> (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for <>
```

Also - Azure documentation on this seems to very poor, if I switch `ENV ARTIFACTS_KEYRING_NONINTERACTIVE_MODE false` it prompts my Azure DevOps pipeline to authenticate intercatively which is not what I want.

How can I install a Python package published in Azure Artifacts as part of my Azure Pipeline Docker task automatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I install a Python package published in Azure Artifacts as part of my Azure Pipeline Docker task automatically?

We could use the [PipAuthenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/pip-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task to populates the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable:

> It authenticates with your artifacts feed and per the docs, will store
>   the location of a config file that can be used to connect in the
>   PYPIRC_PATH environment variable.

Then pass it in the build arg:

```
arguments: --build-arg INDEX_URL=$(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL)
```

You could check this document [Consuming Azure Pipelines Python artifact feeds in Docker](https://gist.github.com/noelbundick/0262aa0f37ec3f9a179137c622b6280d) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - it does help a lot. It worked although for my use case I had to add onlyAddExtraIndex: true on PipAuthenticate@1 task.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that, as has been discussed in the linked article, the secret ENV variable content of `INDEX_URL` is included in the built Docker image. Fortunately, the author does provide a solution to that.

Comment: Everytime the pipeline runs, I am getting a new value for the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` - this results in the docker image layer being re-built (cannot take advantage of caching concept). Is there any solution to this?

Comment: This is fine on Azure, but any suggestion on a smooth workflow to build this in a local dev environment? I can edit pip.conf and authenticate with Azure Artifacts on my host machine using the keyring. But when building the docker container locally, the docker build process cannot authenticate.

Answer (score 7):

To add to the accepted answer, here is a somewhat more complete code example:

#### azure-pipelines.yml

```
- task: PipAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeeds: 'my_artifacts_feed'
    # 'onlyAddExtraIndex' populates PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL env variable
    onlyAddExtraIndex: True

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Build Docker Image'
  inputs:
    command: build
    dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
    tags: |
      $(tag)
    arguments: --build-arg INDEX_URL=$(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL)
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-buster

# add an URL that PIP automatically searches (e.g., Azure Artifact Store URL)
ARG INDEX_URL
ENV PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=$INDEX_URL

COPY requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Note that, if you use `buildAndPush` command instead of `build`, --build-arg will be ignored and thus `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` will be empty and the pip install will fail

Comment: This is fine on Azure, but any suggestion on a smooth workflow to build this in a local dev environment? I can edit pip.conf and authenticate with Azure Artifacts on my host machine using the keyring. But when building the docker container locally, the docker build process cannot authenticate.

Comment: @LeonardFeehan you can pass manually the URL with you access token, that you generate via azure